# How to test stdin function in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, macos, xctest

I have a `readline` function which waits for input from stdin. When I run the function in XCTest, it shows a prompt and waits for input. How to pass an input string so that the `readline` can read it from `stdin` in `XCTest` case?

```
char *input = readline(prompt);
XCTAssertEqualObjects(input, [@"hello" UTF8String]);   // ?
```

Comment: Change `readline` to take a file handle, and pass it a handle to the file containing `hello` during the test. Production callers would be passing `stdin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a `MockStdIOService` class which contains `- (NSString *)readString;` method which will read into a variable `input`. I set the `input` variable and call this method.